# Shared Google Drive folder download issue: files are missing

Tags: google-drive

**Setup**
Alice is using a shared folder with Bob on google drive. The folder was created by Alice and then shared with Bob. 
Bob creates subfolders in the shared folder using the browser (Chrome on Macbook). Of course this subfolders are also automatically shared with Alice.

**Problem**
The folders created by Bob are visible to Alice in the browser (Chrome on Windows 10) but:

- are not automatically downloaded via the gdrive client (even though
  visible in gdrive client preferences, selective folder download etc)
- are only partially downloaded when the whole shared folder is
  downloaded in the browser by Alice (zipped)

**Where is this weird behavior coming from?**

Answer (score 2):

This might not be related to sharing at all; there's an existing bug where Google Drive downloads will simply randomly be missing tons of files, even if they're your own files. Here's a thread about it: https://support.google.com/drive/thread/4142625?hl=en